# hide parent based on childs content

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

I am trying to hide the parent-div based on the child's content:

```
<div class="featurevalue">Number 1: <span class="value">1</span></div>
<div class="featurevalue">Number 2: <span class="value">0</span></div>
<div class="featurevalue">Number 3: <span class="value">1</span></div>
```

Currently I am using this javascript, but it hides all div's with the same class on the page. I need it to only hide the parent div.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var x = $("span.value").text();
        if (x == 0){
            $("div.featurevalue").hide();
        };    
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `.each()` and `$(this).parent()`. Or iterate over all `.featurevalue`s and check their children. (also, not nearly enough research prior to posting)

Comment: Which parent `div` you want to hide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one line solution with `contains` selector:

```js
$("span.value:contains(0)").closest("div.featurevalue").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="featurevalue">Number 1: <span class="value">1</span></div>
<div class="featurevalue">Number 2: <span class="value">0</span></div>
<div class="featurevalue">Number 3: <span class="value">1</span></div>
```

Or if you dont wan´t to use `closest()` or `parent()` just use `has()` selector:

```
$("div.featurevalue:has(span.value:contains(0))").hide();
```

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("span.value").each(function(){
        var x = $(this).text();
        if (x == 0) {
            $(this).closest(".featurevalue").hide();
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Is it okay now @freedomn

Comment: Fixed it for you - could be improved by adding an explanation, eg "loop through each value and use closest to get the relevant parent".  But essentially, this is a valid answer.

Comment: @freedomn-m  Thank you for the comments. Will keep this in mind while posting next answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get span elements with specified text, then travse up using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to target div and `.hide()` them

```js
$("span.value").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === "0"
})
.closest("div.featurevalue")
.hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="featurevalue">Number 1: <span class="value">1</span></div>
<div class="featurevalue">Number 2: <span class="value">0</span></div>
<div class="featurevalue">Number 3: <span class="value">1</span></div>
```

Comment: Best answer. Did not know `.filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

Loop the element with `each()` and check the value and hide the parent with `$(this).parent().hide()`

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.value').each(function(){
      if ($(this).text() == 0){
        $(this).parent().hide();
      };
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="featurevalue">Number 1: <span class="value">1</span></div>
<div class="featurevalue">Number 2: <span class="value">0</span></div>
<div class="featurevalue">Number 3: <span class="value">1</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `.parent()` jQuery function to target the specific parents and `.each()` to iterate through all children:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("span.value").each(function( index ) {
      if ($(this).text() == '0') {
        $(this).parent("div.featurevalue").hide();
      }
    });
  })
})(jQuery);
```

Alternativly you can use `.closest()` like @patilprashant6792 postulates.

Answer (score 0):

Check this below code. We dont need to loop through the elements we can simply use the filter. Here i have added a class "hide" to the parent.

```
 $('.featurevalue span').filter(':contains("0")').parents('.featurevalue').addClass('hide');
```

Comment: Then why use `.filter` at all?